# strtok doesn't tokenize the char* neither is this program printing any data

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, strtok

This is the program:

```
#include <QPoint>
#include <string.h>
#include <QList>
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int y = 14;
    char * str = new char [y];
    str = "23,211,23,211";

    char *pch;
    std::cout << "\nSplitting string into tokens: \n" << str;

    pch = strtok (str,",");
    QList <int> p;
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "\npch:" << pch;
        p.push_back (atoi (pch));
        pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }


    std::cout << "Length of p " <<  p.length() << std::endl;

    QPoint first;
    first.setX               (p[0]);
    first.setY               (p[1]);

    QPoint second;
    second.setX              (p[2]);
    second.setY              (p[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is: 
[image]

What point am I missing?

Comment: why are you using `strtok` in C++ ?

Comment: I couldn't find any simple function for returning string parts based on tokens in c++. @PiotrS.

Comment: `char * str = new char [y]; str = "23,211,23,211"` That would be a memory leak in two short lines. The  ensuing modification of a read-only string literal only furthers the chaos.

Comment: You can try to use `QString::split` to do it. like that: `QStringList list = str.split(",");`

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, could you please enlighten in detail as an answer how it should be corrected?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Vlad already has an answer up describe the problem I referred to. It is definitely worth reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several bugs in your code. First of all there is a memory leak. At first you allocated dynamically memory and its address was assigned to  pointer `str`

```
char * str = new char [y];
```

And then you reassigned the pointer with the address of string literal `"23,211,23,211"`

```
str = "23,211,23,211";
```

So the address of the allocated memory is lost.

String literals may not be modified neither in C++ nor in C while function `strtok` tries to change the string passed to it as an argument. So the program has undefined behaviour.

I think you mean the following.

```
char * str = new char [y];
strcpy( str, "23,211,23,211" );
```

Also in general case the length of `p` can be equal to zero. So you may not use the subscript operator with `p` without checking that it has a non-zero length.

Instead of C function `strtok` you could use string stream `std::istringstream` declared in header `<sstream>`.

Take into account that you should use header `<cstring>` instead of `<string.h>` in C++.

```
#include <cstring>
```